# Can I apply 'set_index' using sql syntax in a similar manner to pandas?

Tags: python, sqlite

In pandas I can use 'set_index' to set an index column. For example, I can change the following:
[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eahH5.png)

To:

[Updated dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVhRe.png)

I have this dataframe stored as table in SQLite. However, it is in the same format as the original dataframe. I want to set the 'Date' column as the index within the SQL environment. Can I use SQL syntax to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite you can have zero or more indexes. You can remove an index using the DROP INDEX statement (see https://sqlite.org/lang_dropindex.html). To create an index use the CREATE INDEX statement (see https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html).

EDIT: If you are in a Python environment (rather than Pandas) then it might be easiest to do this:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3 . connect ( 'club.sqlite' )
c = conn . cursor ( )

c . execute ( 'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS forename_index ON members(forename)' ) 

conn . close ( )
```

The second parameter of **read_sql_query** expects one of three different open connections to a SQL database. I don't know which you have, or whether it's open.

Comment: Bill, thank you I have been trying to use the 'CREATE INDEX' with no luck via the _read_sql_query_ function in Python . My SQL table is named 'table' , my database is named 'db'. This is what I tried in python: `df2 = read_sql_query('CREATE INDEX newindex ON table(Date)',db)`. This is the error returned: _ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically_.

Comment: Bill, I am connected to the database. I tried with the following: `con = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')` and `df = read_sql_query('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS Date_index ON table(Date)', con)`
My error is `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

`

Comment: I also tried the following alternative:  `cur = con.cursor()` then, `cur.execute("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS Date_index ON table(Date);")`. Afterwards,I queried using: `df = sqlr('SELECT * FROM table ', con)` , but the table did not change at all.

Comment: Joseph, I can't tell what's wrong, and I'll say now what I probably should have said before: You should submit another question. As always, include the smallest chunk of code that displays the problem you're having, along with a few rows of sample data.